# Assistance with sed

Tags: sed

I need to use sed or something to change a line in a file from

```
        line1_shortname: "785150 @ TL"
```

to

```
        line1_shortname: "785150"
```

Basically there is a lot of white spaces at the start of that line so basically I need to find the line 'line1_shortname:' and then remove anything after the 6 numbers but before the "

Answer (score 0):

If the six numbers are always space separated from the rest of the double quoted string, one way might be to just use a capture group to grab anything not a space character any number of times. This would deal with the case where you have any number of digits. This might work for you:

```
sed '/^\s*line1_shortname:/s/"\([^ ]*\).*"/"\1"/' file
```